# How to import from E00 Interchange File with ArcGIS 10.8?

Tags: esri-coverage-format, e00, arcgis-10.8

I have a dataset in old ArcInfo E00 Interchange format.  In the past I could extract the data from this by using the "Import From Interchange File" tool in the Coverage toolbox, however this toolbox doesn't appear to be present in ArcGIS 10.8.

I searched around for more info and found the ArcGIS [Coverage toolbox licensing](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/coverage-toolbox/coverage-toolbox-license.htm) page that said I needed ArcInfo Workstation installed to use these old tools.  Unfortunately I don't have access to ArcInfo Workstation anymore.

> Import From Interchange File - Requires ArcInfo Workstation installed

How does one go about extracting from E00 in more recent versions of ArcMap that don't have ArcInfo Workstation?

Comment: You can use GDAL to do this. https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/avce00.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcGIS Desktop (but not ArcGIS Pro) has a script tool included, called "Import from E00" - it can be found in the Conversion Tools > To Coverage toolset.

[image]

Just select the E00 file and give an output location and filename, and the tool will output a coverage.

Once the coverage has been produced, you can then use the Import Feature Class to Geodatabase (etc.) tool to convert the coverage into a geodatabase feature class.  This can then be used (edited, etc.) in both ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro.

[image]